# MS Dynamics CRM E-mail and Phone call migration using scribe online

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, scribe-workbench

I was migrating data from **MS on-premise CRM** to **online MS Dynamics 2016 CRM**.
But was not able to migrate emails and phone call activities using scribe online.
The problem is with Email "**To**" and "**From**" fields, which are of type activity party with partly list (i.e multiple recipient of different entities , like account or contact)
Can you please help me in understanding the process and how can I migrate activities.
Please do suggest if the emails and phone calls can be migrated with any other tools.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Activity parties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328549.aspx) are always a headache and it's really important to understand how they work in order to avoid a lot of problems during migrations.

[This is a really good](http://www.powerobjects.com/2013/06/27/activity-parties-and-dynamics-crm-crm-migrations-scribe/) blog article about how to migrate emails, party list included, using Scribe (it uses Scribe Insight-OnPrem but it should not affect in this case):

> The best way to do this is to migrate the email records over to from
>   the source to target CRM with the same GUID on both sides. Then you
>   can simply run a migration of Activity Party records and directly
>   associate the GUIDs. This is in effect taking a replica of the data in
>   the source CRM and migrating it to the target CRM, keeping everything
>   the same. You would map activity party ActivityID, PartyID, and
>   PartyTypeCode to one another directly. You would then set the
>   activityfieldname to be the field you want records written for (ie.
>   To, Cc, or Bcc). You would need to change this value for each run to
>   get all records over, as if you specify To, then Cc and Bcc will fail,
>   and you will have to run them next.